# Testflight (app version) download internal test does not finish

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect, testflight

1. Using Apple's Testflight app and create an internal testing build
   (Xcode 6)
2. send out notifications
3. test user clicks on notification and starts the download
4. download gets to 90%(estimate) then stops

I have tried this on two different accounts with two different apps and the result is the same. Any ideas out there? It seems the app does get downloaded but the download process didn't finish and iTunes connect doesn't know the user has that version (the latest build field doesn't update).

Comment: My experience with test flight points to an error from their side. Most of the times, letting some time to by solves the problem.

Comment: I tried this a couple days in a row, deleting the app an again doing the link from the email and it appears to be working now.

Comment: You should open an issue in Apple Bug Reporter. More bug reports will push them to fix this critical bug as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me just now. And I have a solution for you:

Despite the "Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file", include Info.plist in Copy Bundle Resources.

I did that, uploaded a new build, and it finally installed completely on TestFlight after 4 other builds prior to it that got stuck at 90% forever.

Comment: I'll try that if I hit it again

Comment: @sarhdan So, how is it going? After you try.

Comment: This was a very old post from early beta of test flight and the issue eventually resolved itself